# Is there a (mostly) objective study regarding minimum wage and job growth?

Tags: reference-request, wages, minimum-wage

I think over the course of the past couple years the topic of wealth-inequality and living wages has become increasingly commonplace, and really one of the most debated topics (among us casuals at least).

Personally, I don't believe that "unbiased" studies exist, but is there some sort of mostly objective study (or really just a good one) done that correlates job growth/loss with the rising of minimum wage, or conversely, the abolishment of a minimum wage?

Comment: I don't agree that unbiased studies don't exist. I would say you would have to look harder in mainstream media for sure. In academia, I don't think bias is anywhere near as prevalent. Maybe I am naive.

Comment: Also, not a duplicate, but the answer to your question is also the answer to this question. http://economics.stackexchange.com/a/430/40

Comment: My answer here links to a survey of 102 academic studies on this issue. Even if you don't believe that the authors of each paper are unbiased, the collective message of 102 papers should help to eliminate some of the bias. http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/empirical-data-on-demand-for-minimum-wage-jobs-in-the-usa/6492#6492